# Markov inequality for $|X-EX|^4$.

Tags: probability

We know that Chebyshev's inequality for variable $X$ is the same as Markov's inequality for $|X-EX|^2$.  I aimed to find inequality for $
|X-EX|^4$.

From Markov's inequality:
$P(|X-EX| \ge t) = P\left(\left(|X-EX|^2\right)^2 \ge \left(t^2\right)^2\right) \le \frac{E\left(|X -EX|^4\right)}{t^4}$
I don't know is it possible to simplify $\frac{E\left(|X -EX|^4\right)}{t^4}$.
Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

If your basic Markov inequality says something like $$P(Y \ge a) \le \dfrac{E[Y]}{a}$$ if $P(Y \ge 0)=1$, and you let $Y=|X-E[X]|^4$ then you have $$P(|X-E[X]|^4 \ge a) \le \dfrac{E[|X-E[X]|^4]}{a}$$

and you could multiply this out and manipulate it, with $$|X-E[X]|^4=(X-E[X])^4 = E[X^4]-4E[X^3]\mu_X^{\,} +6\sigma_X^2\mu_X^2+3\mu_X^4$$ but it will not provide as neat a result as Chebyshev's inequality.